# How to send sms by plivo api it require autoload.php

Tags: php, cakephp, plivo

How to send sms by plivo api it say 
require vendor/autoload.php
But i cannot find any autoload.php , it have also composer.json
when i run this is get error

Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found

here the my code

```
<form action="send_sms_from_browser.php" method="post">
From No:<input type="text" name="From"><br><br>
To&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;No:<input type="text" name="To"><br><br>
Message:<br>
<textarea name="Text" rows="3" cols="30" >Message Text</textarea><br>     <br>
<input type="submit" value="Send SMS">
</form> 


error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Plivo\RestAPI;
$to = $_POST['To'];
$from = $_POST['From'];
$text = $_POST['Text'];
echo "<br/>Sent Message info:<br/><br/>To: $to<br/>";
echo "From: $from  <br/>";
echo "Message: $text <br/>";
$auth_id = 'Auth id';
$auth_token = "Token";

$p = new RestAPI($auth_id, $auth_token);

print_r($p);
// Send a message
$params = array(
        'src' => "$from",
        'dst' => "$to",
        'text' => "$text",
        'type' => 'sms',
    );
$response = $p->send_message($params);
echo $response[0];
if (array_shift(array_values($response)) == "202")
{
    echo "<br/><br/>Message status: Sent";
}
else
{
    echo "<br/><br/>Error: Please ensure that From number is a valid";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you now i solved this by myself this is the code hope this is useful for you guys..

```
$ch = curl_init();
$data = '{"src": "source number with country code","dst": "receiver with country code", "text": "Hi, text from Plivo"}';


 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/AUTH_ID/Message/");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type: application/json"
 ));


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "AUTH_ID:TOKEN_ID");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);exit;
```